# Using the $_POST method while running foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach

I am struggling with this one. I have a foreach loop:

```
if(isset($_POST['chkboxes'])) {
  foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) {
        echo '- '.$chkbox."<br />";
  }
        '<input type="hidden" name="options" id="options" value=" ' . $chkbox . '"/>';
        echo '<br /><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Confirm"/> </form> </td></tr></table>';
```

As you can see from above, I've tried to have an hidden input with the value of `$chkbox` where on my new php page I use:

```
if(isset($_POST['options'])){
    $options = $_POST['options'];
}
```

I'm trying to display all the items checked, or `$chkbox` on the new php page. The other form works perfectly, it's just grabbing the information from this foreach loop, and trying to get that information to display correctly on the new php page.

Here is what my entire code looks like:

```
<?php

require("database.php"); //connect to the database

if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE id='$id' "); 
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
        exit();
    }


//DYNAMIC PHP PULLING IN THE DATA AND SPITTING OUT THE RESULTS
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $picturepath = $row['picturepath'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];

    $dynamiclist = '<table align="center" width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
                        <tr height="100"></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="22%" valign="top" align="left"><img style="border: #66cc33 5px solid;" src="./menupictures/' .$picturepath . '" height="200" width="200" border="1"/></td>
                            <td width="20%" valign="top" align="left">' . $name . ' <br />$' . $price . '<br /><br />
                               <td valign="top" align="left"> <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value=" ' . $id . '"/>';


    echo $dynamiclist;
    echo "Your Item Options: <br /><br />";
}

if(isset($_POST['chkboxes'])) {
  foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) {
        echo '- '.$chkbox."<br />";
        '<input type="hidden" name="options[]" id="options" value=" ' . $chkbox . '"/>';
  }
        echo '<br /><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Confirm"/> </form> </td></tr></table>';
        echo'  <table width="90%"><tr><td width="30%"></td>
        <td width="21%"></td>
        <td><font><a href="irohomepage.php">Cancel This Item</a></font></td></tr></table>';
}
mysqli_close($con); //close the db connection

?>

<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: Is your question why it doesn't *echo* the hidden input field?

Comment: Well, I'd like to use 

if(isset($_POST['options'])){
    $options = $_POST['options'];
}

And then on the new php page, I echo out the information. I just need help pulling in that data from the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if I had understood you well but maybe this is what you would like to achieve

```
if(isset($_POST['chkboxes'])) 
{
    foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) 
    {
        echo '- '.$chkbox."<br />";
        '<input type="hidden" name="options[]" id="options" value=" ' . $chkbox . '"/>';
    }
}

echo '<br /><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Confirm"/> </form> </td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: I tried that and it still does not display the checkboxes. However, on my new page, when I change my:

if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $options = $_POST['button'];
}

It posts the value "Confirm"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have one bug in your code:

you are checking

```
$_POST['chkboxes']
```

when you should be checking

```
$_POST['options']
```

because you have named them so:

```
name="options[]"
```

So - use the same name both in your html and your php code.

Comment: I know. I only want the checkboxes that were checked. Thank you for the tip, though!